# Is there a channel setting to ask for confirmation if a member does @here?

Tags: slack

Is there a way to make Slack ask for confirmation if a user makes a `@here` mention in the channel?  I heard Slack does ask for confirmation for `@channel` mentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There won't be a built-in feature to configure this but we could build a custom app to mimic what you requesting. When someone posts a message, we can modify the @here to _here and suppress it. Then, our custom app should prompt whether they would like to really notify everyone who is online now. Upon their confirmation, we can modify _here to @here.

If modifying messages did not work, we could delete and repost after user's confirmation.

[image: Slack setting that let's configure how it should prompt]